# taking decimal inputs for x-editable field

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I am using [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) with bootstrap

I have the following html field defined

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4">Service Charges(%)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 hoverEdit">
        <a class="editableAccount" id="serviceTax"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the following script defined to make the field editable

```
$('.editableAccount').editable({
    type : 'number',
    title : 'Enter New Value',
    success : function(response, newValue) {
        updateAccount(this.id, newValue);
    }
});
```

Now when i try to edit the field and enter decimal values i get this

[image]

I want to make this field editable so that i can enter decimal values. I can't see any help on the documentation. Some one please help me here, i am fairly new to html and javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE (Nov 1, 2018)**: Following a recent downvote, I came back to review my answer, and here is what I found out: `selection` is used by x-editable to process the field to be edited, but `selection` is only supposed to work on fields rendered as text, thus using `x-editable` with a number field will either produce an error or just do nothing (see [chrome bug 324360](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=324360) and [415391](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=415391) for details). So use one of the other answers provided in this question, or see [x-editor's github issue #328](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/328) with similar solutions.

Here is my original answer for historical purposes:

---

Inputs of type `number` need a `step` attribute for them to accept decimals.

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/input.number.html#input.number.attrs.step.float

Going out from that, you'll most probably need to use your jQuery call like this:

```
$('.editableAccount').editable({
    type : 'number',
    step: 'any', // <-- added this line
    title : 'Enter New Value',
    success : function(response, newValue) {
        updateAccount(this.id, newValue);
    }
});
```

**Note:** I haven't tested this, it's just the best logical move I think

**EDIT:** Following your comment (thanks!), looks like my suggestion is not working because of a limitation recently introduced in chrome (not sure about other browsers) to number fields no longer allowing selection (source: [selectionStart and SelectionEnd incorrectly available on <input type=email/number>](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=324360)). So what you could try instead, is to change the field type to something else and do your number validation in your `updateAccount` function instead.

Comment: actually i had already tried that. In that case i start getting this error

Comment: Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setSelectionRange' on 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('number') does not support selection.

Comment: I'm sorry, dude... maybe what you could try is to set it as a text or other field instead and add the number validation to your `updateAcctoun` function (in `success`), have you tried that?

Comment: no problem man, the idea here is to display the information and have it editable in place, meaning user can edit the displayed information by clicking on it and thats why i am using .editable() method from the x-editable plugin. So making the field itself a text field might not work for me. But thanks a lot for your comments. I really appreciate them.

Comment: hm... do you mean you'd want it to validate while you're typing? wouldn't adding another, separate function to the same class do the trick? just wondering...

Comment: actually i understood you wrong. i saw your edit to your answer and i did what you suggested. Thanks :)

Comment: I see your edit has been rejected, and rightly so. The implementation has been done by yourself, not me, so you shouldn't give me credit for that. You could still upvote or select my answer as the correct one, or do the same with @BabyAzerty answer, really up to you... ;)

Comment: why would you want to add another plugin instead of adding a line of code to an existing one...?

Answer (score 2):

I used the x-editable `shown` event and set the `step` attribute there:

```
var edit = (function () {

    var $editable = $('.editable');

    var setInputStep = function(editable, step) {
        var input = editable.input;
        if (input.type == 'number')
            input.$input.attr('step', step);
    };

    var shownEvent = function (e, editable) {
        setInputStep(editable, 0.01);
    };

    var init = function () {
        $editable.editable();
        $editable.on('shown', shownEvent);
    };

    return {
        init: init
    };

})();

edit.init();
```

And in html make sure to set the `data-type="number"`

```
<a href="#" class="editable" data-type="number" data-pk="1" data-url="/edit/" data-title="Enter Value" data-name="value">Sample</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using text field and test for decimal validation :

```
$('.editableAccount').editable({
    type: 'text',
    title: 'Enter New Value',
    success: function(response, newValue) {
        updateAccount(this.id, newValue);
    },
    validate: function(value) {
        if ($.trim(value) == '') {
            return 'This field is required';
        }
        var regexp = new RegExp("^\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,2}){0,1}$");
        if (!regexp.test(value)) {
            return 'This field is not valid';
        }
    }
});
```

Also do a validation server-side for security reason. You can use something very basic like `is_numeric()` (in PHP) but that will accept "funny" values like hex or binary values.

Comment: RegExp must be in camelCase, other solution is to put the regular expresion within / / `var regexp = /^\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,2}){0,1}$/;`

Answer (score 1):

Use data-step="any" , Instead of step="any"

```html
<span id="cost" data-type="number" data-pk="1" data-title="cost" class="editable editable-click" data-step="any" onclick="callFunctionEditable('cost');">58.54545</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In My Case I Added Custom `data`

Then On Some Sort Of Event A Added The Pattern Needed.

```js
$("a[data-inputclass='onlyLongFloat']").click(function (e) {
    $(".onlyLongFloatAndNumber").attr({
        'pattern': '[0-9]+([\\.,][0-9]+)?',
        'title' : "The Fields Needs To Be An Float ",
        'step': '0.00001',
        'id': 'onlyLongFloatAndNumber'
    });
});
```